# spelling matching using Jaro-Winkler Distance to calculate the similarity of two strings

Tags: java, android

I'm tring to do auto-correct for spelling and using Jaro-Winkler strategy .
I have list of suggestions and the types word is ranked with the suggestion words.
The problem I'm facing, when word "ans"/"anf"/"anr" is types ,"an" is given the heights rank when compared. "and" is way back in the score list . Therefore "ans"/"anf"/"anr" are replaced with "an" instead of "and" .

Any suggestion how should I solve this, or are there any other algorithm to replace "ans"/"anf"/"anr" perfectly with "and" not "an" ?

Comment: Just wondering, did you ever open source the code to this?  I just implemented Jaro-Winkler in C# last weekend.  But be nice to know your test cases. :)

Comment: Look at this QWERTY adaptation on Jaro-Winkler: https://github.com/nilaksh/qwerty-jaro-winkler/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

For general typos, weighting transpositions higher than deletions/additions seems like a good idea.

Assuming your entries are input with a standard keyboard layout(qwerty?), you could do an additional weight based on physical distance between keys. Not sure the best way to do that logically. Off the top of my head, you could create a 2d array containing the keyboard map, and compare actual(pythagorean) distance.

Given a map with "Q"=[0][0], "W"=[0][1], "A"=[1][0], the distance between A->Q would be 1, Q->W = 1, and Q->S = sqrt(2). That should give you something to weight distances with.

There's probably a much cleaner implementation of the distance calculation, but just spitballing here.